# Facebook doesn't scrape existing/working link. CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection

Tags: php, facebook

I have a page to show items which I want to be shared on Facebook. Now the url works, only facebook cannot reach the pages and gives the error:

CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Link to scrape:

http://www.venzo.co.nl/index.php?r=agenda/index&item=17

Does anyone have any idea what's why this is happening?

Comment: Look into your server’s access log to see what request the FB scraper actually sends.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that the slash in "agenda/index" is the problem. you should not use a slash without encoding in an url parameter.

It works fine if you just use the basic URL.

If that is not the problem, maybe this thread helps: http://www.venzo.co.nl/index.php?r=agenda/index&item=17

...or this one: https://www.sourcecoast.com/forums/jfbconnect/jfbconnect-joomla-25-support/7322-url-returned-a-bad-http-response-code-on-facebok-debugger

Although i am very positive that it is indeed a problem with the parameters, because this works perfectly fine: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.venzo.co.nl%2Findex.php

Also try NOT to urlencode the og:url parameter (Use "&" instead of "&").

Comment: encoding doesn't make any difference. I actually encoded the url in the first place, and changed it to this. But the error stays the same..

Comment: i´ve added some more ideas. happy hunting :)

Answer (score 0):

I moved everything to another server and everything works fine there. It seems that the server was blocking the facebook scraper. So the URL is not a problem. Though, this url format is a standard in YII which I use. A solution for the slash and some more flexibility use the url 'path' setting. Allows you to use custom urls too:

[routes in yii](http://www.larryullman.com/2013/02/18/understanding-routes-in-the-yii-framework/)

Have a good day!